# Sort Pandas dataframe by custom values

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

> I have a DataFrame car_accessories as above. I want to order by
> columns a,b,c,car,price_band. While a,b,c,car columns are order in
> ascending order of alphabets column price band is ordered by the
> ascending value of price range.  ≤ 95.0$ will come first   95.0$ >
> price ≥ 115.0$  will come second  > 115.0$ will be last.  Price band
> will always have 3 category of values, one with less than and equal to
> eg., ≤95.0$, Second with a range eg., 95.0$ > price ≥ 115.0$,, third
> with greater than eg., > 115.0$
>
> The sorted column will look like.

[image]